# Odd behavior when using uppercase(combined with underscore) for column names in Hibernate(deployed on JBoss 5.1.0), for MySql DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jboss5.x

I'm trying to specify column name using the @Column annotation:

```
@Column(name="ID") //also tried with @Column(name="[ID]") and @Column(name=""\ID"\")
private int id; 

@Column(name="TINY_IMAGE")
private String tinyUrl;
```

But, the hibernate (or MySQL?) gives the names 'id' and 'tinyUrl' for the above mentioned
columns, respectively.

However, when I use the code bellow, columns' names in the join table are just fine (SHOE_ID and ARTICLE_ID):

```
@JoinTable(name="SHOE_ARTICLE",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SHOE_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ARTICLE_ID")})
```

Here is the content of persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"  
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  

         version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="YSPers">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/ySDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
                  value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
         <!-- property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/-->
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

How can I tell hibernate to use "name" property of @Column annotation for the column name?

Comment: seems if hibernate defaults back. Are you sure that your configuration is correct and all neccesary annotations are placed right?

Comment: 1. what OS 2. which @Column annotation

Comment: How are you telling Hibernate about your mapped classes?

Comment: Via annotations - @Entity
@Table(name="SHOE_IMAGE")
public class ShoeImage implements Serializable {

Comment: No, that's how you're mapping the class. Somewhere, you have to tell Hibernate which classes it should be managing. Also, use the @<user> to get people's attention in comments like this. e.g. @Ryan: <whatever> will notify me that you've said something specifically to me.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart: thanx. Well, I'm not telling to Hibernate anything explicitly, maybe because JBoss (5.1.0) already does that. Or I don't understand your question...

Comment: Okay, I'm not familiar enough with JBoss to talk about that. My only guess at this point is that your entity is getting mapped without the annotations getting picked up. That could happen if it's mapped in XML and you just don't know it, but that depends on how Hibernate is [configured with the mapped classes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html). It has to be done somehow.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart: Well, that's strange, because hibernate uses correct name for the generated table (@Table(name="SHOE_IMAGE"), and it would be veeeery odd if it escapes class attributes' annotation and not classes' annotation, which is case here. Anyways, thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Bozho: Windows Vista, javax.persistence.Column annotation type.

Comment: @marc: I think everything is right, I just put persistence.xml content in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might have mixed annotations on both fields and getters in the class hierarchy.

Make sure to put you annotations in on place. The target (field or getter) scanned by Hibernate depends on where you put the `@Id` annotation: make sure you put your `@Column` annotations on the same target. I usually recommend the getter for various reasons.

By the way, the way to quote a column name is by using backticks @Column(name="`MY_ID`")

Comment: Awesome!! That's the right answer. Thank you so much, Emmanuel. Unfortunately, I cannot give you my vote, because my reputation is under 15.

Comment: Also, I have noticed that hibernate sometimes has problem with applying the rules from annotations over class attributes, but has no problem to apply the rules from annotations over getters..it seems odd, anyways..I know how to deal with it now ;)